# Change Action Bar gradient background color when horizontal scrolling

Tags: android

i want to change the background (gradient color) of the ActionBar at the same time i scroll horizontally.

I create a subclass of ViewPager and override onInterceptTouchEvent method to get the orientation (left - right) and try to get a percentage of the scroll. (I start in 0% and when the page changes, it's my 100%).

I use this percentage to transform actionbar background from one color to other color. Example: Blue -> Green In RGB (0,0,255) to (0,238,0).

```
    @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    float x = ev.getX();

     switch (ev.getAction()){
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             mStartDragX = x;
             break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mStartDragX > x){
                    //Left scroll
                    float percent = (mStartDragX - x) / screen_width * 100;
                    changeColorActionBar(true, percent);
                    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
                }
                else if (mStartDragX < x){
                    //Right scroll
                    float percent = (x - mStartDragX)  / screen_width * 100;
                    changeColorActionBar(false, percent);
                    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

The problems is that this method works when i lift up my finger. But if i scroll to the left repeatedly without changing the page, the background changes from blue to green.

So i don't know wich method i must override for evaluate the displacement without lifting the finger.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `CustomViewPager` instead of your and you must override the `onTouch`, cause this will request all time when you are in scrolling:

---

[image][image]

---

### CustomViewPager.class

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

float mStartDragX;
int screen_width;

android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public void setActivity(MainActivity activity) {
    this.screen_width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    this.actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    float x = ev.getX();

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mStartDragX > x) {
                //Left scroll
                float percent = (mStartDragX - x) / screen_width * 100;
                changeColorActionBar(true, percent);
            } else if (mStartDragX < x) {
                //Right scroll
                float percent = (x - mStartDragX) / screen_width * 100;
                changeColorActionBar(false, percent);
            }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

public void changeColorActionBar(boolean toRight, float percent) {

    int result = (int) ((percent * 255) / 100);
    int part = 255 - result;

    if (toRight) {
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0, part, result)));
    } else {
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0, result, part)));
    }
}
```

}